# react-native-animation : update state when animation color has changed

Tags: react-native

I want to `update` the `state` when animation color has changed.

When the animation changes from white to red, I want to update the `state` and display the updated state in the text label.

[image]

This is my code:

```
export default class AnimationHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  this.state = {
       scrollY:new Animated.Value(0),
       headerColor:'white'
    }
  }

  render() {

    const HeaderHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 200],
      outputRange: [120, 120],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    const AnimateHeaderBackgroundColor = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [ 70, 70  ],
        outputRange: [ 'transparent', 'red'],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    return (
      <View

      style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={{width:'100%', height:HeaderHeight, backgroundColor:AnimateHeaderBackgroundColor, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize:30}}>Animated Header</Text>


      </Animated.View>

       <ScrollView
                  scrollEventThrottle={16}
                  onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }])}
                  style={{width:'100%', backgroundColor:'gray'}}>
                  <View style={{width:'100%', height:1000, backgroundColor:'blue', justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:30}}>headerColor:</Text>

//////////////////I want to display the updated state here

                    <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:30}}>white</Text>
                  </View>
       </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the value of the animation

```
const animatedListener = this.state.animatedValue.addListener((progress) => {
  this.setState({ progress: progress.value });
  console.log(progress.value)
});
```

Just remember to remove the listener when done

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.state.animatedValue.removeListener(animatedListener);
  //or use for many listeners
  this.state.animatedValue.removeAllListeners()
}
```

It is important to note that if you use `userNativeDriver` you will not be able to listen and always receive the initial value

Comment: thanks for the answer. It really helps. I got two questions tho. 1) Do I place the `const animatedListener` inside the render? 2)Whats the reason for removing the listener?

Comment: 1.not into render into componentDidMount 2.You need to remove the listener so it doesn't continue to listen
And create a memory leak 3.Please confirm my answer (-:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. According to react-native document [react native animation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#responding-to-the-current-animation-value)
I could use `Animated.Value.addListener` to check my animation state.

I could simply add:

```
componentDidMount() {

      this.state.scrollY.addListener(({value}) => {
        if(value > 70){
          this.setState({headerColor:'red'})
          console.log('red')
        }
        if(value<70){
          this.setState({headerColor:'white'})
          console.log('white')

        }
        this._value = value, console.log(value,'value')});
      }
```

Then, in my text label I just display the state:

```
this.state.headerColor
```